# AngularJS controller infinite requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the simple controller function that counts how many answers there are in each question:

```
$scope.countAnswers = function(questionid) {
  AnswersQueries.getAnswers(questionid, function(answers) {
    var answersCount = answers.length;
    return answersCount;
  });
};
```

HTML

```
<!-- Inside ng-repeat -->
<div>{{countAnswers(question._id)}}</div>
```

Service

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('AnswersQueries', function ($resource) {
  return {

      getAnswers: function(questionId, callback) {

        // Define resource
        var data = $resource('api/answers?questionid=' + questionId);

        // Fire the get call
        data.query().$promise.then(function(answer){

           // Return answer in callback
           callback(answer);
        });
      }
  };
});
```

And when I try to reload the page, it makes a TON of requests to count questions... the correct requests, but it never stops:

i.e....

```
GET /api/answers?questionid=54ae02aec07933920b000001 200 28ms - 371b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec71cdd9a29d210000001 200 28ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec75bdd9a29d210000002 200 32ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54adf9f0e0913a590a000001 200 7ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54ae02aec07933920b000001 200 14ms - 371b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec71cdd9a29d210000001 200 4ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec75bdd9a29d210000002 200 4ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec75bdd9a29d210000002 200 15ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54ae02aec07933920b000001 200 18ms - 371b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec71cdd9a29d210000001 200 17ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54adf9f0e0913a590a000001 200 20ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54ae02aec07933920b000001 200 17ms - 371b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54adf9f0e0913a590a000001 200 7ms - 2b
GET /api/answers?questionid=54aec71cdd9a29d210000001 200 9ms - 2b
```

Console error (I think I can troubleshoot now... didn't see this before because page was frozen):

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

What could be happening?

Comment: With this piece of code displayed in the question how do we know what is actually going on? Don't you think you need to show minimal replicable code?

Comment: I thought I remembered it was something to do with the `question` being inside an ng-repeat, but I'll add more code sorry.

Comment: Shouldn't `countAnswers()` return some integer value? But your code shows that the function isn't returning anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it helps resolve the problem, but your `countAnswers` function is wrong.

The line `return answersCount;` returns from the callback function. Your actual `countAnswers` function returns nothing. Since `AnswersQueries.getAnwers` is async, you cannot use its result immediately.

The solution is to store the values in the scope and update in the callback.

```
$scope.counts = {};
$scope.countAnswers = function(questionid) {
  AnswersQueries.getAnswers(questionid, function(answers) {
    $scope.counts[questionid] = answers.length;
  });
};

//call $scope.countAnswers for each question in your scope *once*
```

And html should look like:

```
<div>{{counts[question._id]}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular will attempt to evaluate each binding every time it runs a digest cycle. There are specific conditions that trigger a digest cycle automatically - one of which is the receipt of a response from $resource (actually $http, used by $resource under the hood).

Your template binds to an expression that calls the function `countAnswers`, which makes a new $resource query each time it is called. So, when the app first digests, an http call is made, and when the response is received the app digests again and kicks off another http call... ad nauseum.

One solution to this problem is to cache the result of the http call, so that subsequent calls to 'countAnswers' will return the result of the first http call, rather than making another http call.

For example:

```
var answersCounts = {};
var hasRequestedAnswers = {};
$scope.countAnswers = function(questionid) {
  if (!hasRequestedAnswers[questionid]) {
    AnswersQueries.getAnswers(questionid, function(answers) {
      answersCounts[questionid] = answers.length;
    });
    hasRequestedAnswers[questionid] = true;
  }
  return answersCounts[questionid];
};
```